# Which Licenses to ship within an NW.js - application?

Tags: node.js, chromium, node-webkit, io.js, nw.js

I've just read the section about distributing at the wiki of nw.js

> And since the binary is based on Chromium, multiple open source license > notices are needed including the MIT License, the LGPL, the BSD, the Ms-PL and an MPL/GPL/LGPL tri-license. (This doesn't apply to your code and you don't have to open source your code)

but I don't know where to find the licensing information I shall include for chromium . Or do I have to ship the general text of the mentioned licenses without any copyright information ?

Answer (score 1):

Because I could not find more details about the licensing on NWjs web site I decided to contact the most active contributor to the source code on GitHub (Mr. [Roger Wang](https://github.com/rogerwang)), who kindly replied to my email by saying that

*"Just include credits.html with your application. You can find it in the zip file of NW.js binary."*.

I would anyway make the credits file accessible within the app, maybe you could have a menu item "About/Credits" and display the file with a short introduction to it.

Comment: Thanks for this answer! I looked everywhere... Amazon Music is build on a similar platform, and they host their third-party license information from their website.